# Does a Dual Core ARM CPU have two Program counters ? [bare metal multi core programming]

Tags: arm, multicore, bare-metal

I want to do baremetal programming on a [Dual-core A20 AllWinner ARM CPU](http://www.allwinnertech.com/en/clq/processora/A20.html). I don't have much experience on multi core programming. I have a question regarding bare metal multi core programming.

My assumption is that a Dual Core CPU will have two Program counters so that I can point them to two different codes and run them in parallel.

Is this true ? Could any one explain how is it in the case of an [Dual-core A20 Allwinner CPU](http://www.allwinnertech.com/en/clq/processora/A20.html) ?

Comment: If it didn't, what would be the use of multiple cores? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A dual core CPU will have 2 sets of same registers i.e one set for CPU0 and another set for CPU1.